# Basic IRC Server Protocol overview / tutorial

Tags: network-programming, protocols, network-protocols, irc

I have to develop my own IRC Server for a project for school.
School does not require much and all i have to show them is a functioning
irc server which accepts multiple connections and actually performs the basic tasks
such as opening a room, chatting, banning ..

I developed my own IRC bot when i was younger but building the irc server is much harder,
as i do not have time to make my own research or read the whole RFC of the IRC Server protocol.

so the special is, **do you know any sites/tutorials/articles that describe in short the irc server protocol, so i could develop a basic irc server without reading a whole RFC?**

I know it might piss off some people that i do not actually want to study the protocol but just kind of "copy" it for my school project. this is not the case, i do want to study it as i studied a lot of protocols, and i will. **Right now i do not need to understand it, i just need something working for my project, or i will be left without a grade.**

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2813#section-4 really isn't that bad, and you really only need to read the relatively short section 4.

Answer (score 6):

What language do you use?

[Here](http://me.opengroove.org/2009/10/single-file-irc-server.html) is an working simple irc server written in java by Alex Boyd.

Edit: The source code for got lost in time. Use the [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20120204211817/http://jwutils.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/projects/jircs/src/Connection.java).

Comment: you are my saviour. you just made someone's day around the globe. thank you very much, i do develop in java and that source code is perfect. 

any other solutions and (preferably) articles/totorials will be welcomed.

Answer (score 5):

I see @jous has already answered your query.

For others who want to learn about IRC server development, here is a very good resource - https://www.alien.net.au/irc/index.html